# Uploading an xml direct to ftp

Tags: c#, xml, forms, authentication, ftp

i put this direct below a button:

```
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("Login");
            XmlElement id = doc.CreateElement("id");
            id.SetAttribute("userName", usernameTxb.Text);
            id.SetAttribute("passWord", passwordTxb.Text);
            XmlElement name = doc.CreateElement("Name");
            name.InnerText = nameTxb.Text; 
            XmlElement age = doc.CreateElement("Age");
            age.InnerText = ageTxb.Text;
            XmlElement Country = doc.CreateElement("Country");
            Country.InnerText = countryTxb.Text;
            id.AppendChild(name);
            id.AppendChild(age);
            id.AppendChild(Country);
            root.AppendChild(id);
            doc.AppendChild(root);

            // Get the object used to communicate with the server.  
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://users.skynet.be");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            request.UsePassive = false;
            // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("fa490002", "password");
            // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.  
            StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader();
            byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
            sourceStream.Close();
            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;
            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            response.Close(); 

            MessageBox.Show("Created SuccesFully!");
            this.Close();
```

but i always get an error of the streamreader path, what do i need to place there ?
the meening is, creating an account and when i press the button, an xml file is saved to, ftp://users.skynet.be/testxml/
the filename is from usernameTxb.Text + ".xml".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change the URL to specific filename where you want to save your XML.
2. Sending code:

   ```
           using ( Stream s = request.GetRequestStream() )
           {
               doc.Save( s );
           }
           MessageBox.Show( "Created SuccesFully!" );
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The line below isn't pointing to a file or stream:

```
StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader();
```

**EDIT**

Below I've expanded on what @dzendras posted. If this helps you please accept @dzendras's answer.

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("Login");
        XmlElement id = doc.CreateElement("id");
        id.SetAttribute("userName", usernameTxb.Text);
        id.SetAttribute("passWord", passwordTxb.Text);
        XmlElement name = doc.CreateElement("Name");
        name.InnerText = nameTxb.Text;
        XmlElement age = doc.CreateElement("Age");
        age.InnerText = ageTxb.Text;
        XmlElement Country = doc.CreateElement("Country");
        Country.InnerText = countryTxb.Text;
        id.AppendChild(name);
        id.AppendChild(age);
        id.AppendChild(Country);
        root.AppendChild(id);
        doc.AppendChild(root);

        //Request needs to be in the format: ftp://example.com/path/file.xml or ftp://example.com/file.xml
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://users.skynet.be/" + usernameTxb.Text + ".xml");
        //Specify that we're uploading a file
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        request.UsePassive = false;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("fa490002", "password");

        //Get raw access to the request stream
        using (Stream s = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            //Save the XML doc to it
            doc.Save(s);
        }

        //Push the request to the server and await its response
        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        //We should get a 226 status code back from the server if everything worked out ok
        if (response.StatusCode == FtpStatusCode.ClosingData){
            MessageBox.Show("Created SuccesFully!");
        }else{
            MessageBox.Show("Error uploading file:" + response.StatusDescription);
        }
        response.Close();

        this.Close();
```

Comment: it shows up with a error that there are no construtors thath takes 0 argruments

Comment: what is the path? ftp://users.skynet.be/fa490002 ? Then it says "the given path's form is not suported"